# Package list in EMR master node versus package list in EMR Notebook

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, jupyterhub

I have one EMR cluster up and running. In it, I have one Jupyter Notebook with `pyspark` kernel.

For the master node, I am able to `SSH` into it. I am able to install Python packages in the master node easily, such as :

```
pip install pandas
```

which I can then verify successful with `pip freeze`

However, when I go to the `pyspark` notebook, using `sc.list_packages()`, I see a different list of packages in there. Some package has different version compared to in the master node. Some package (such as `pandas`) does not appear altogether.

Here is the list of `pip freeze` in master node `SSH`.

```
aws-cfn-bootstrap==2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
boto==2.49.0
click==7.1.2
Cython==0.29.30
docutils==0.14
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib==0.15.1
lockfile==0.11.0
lxml==4.5.1
mysqlclient==1.4.2
nltk==3.5
nose==1.3.4
numpy==1.21.6
pandas==1.3.5
py-dateutil==2.2
py4j==0.10.9.5
pybind11==2.9.2
pyspark==3.3.0
pystache==0.5.4
python-daemon==2.2.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python37-sagemaker-pyspark==1.3.0
pytz==2020.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
regex==2020.6.8
scipy==1.7.3
simplejson==3.2.0
six==1.13.0
soupsieve==1.9.5
tqdm==4.46.1
windmill==1.6
```

And here is the package list in the `PySpark` notebook using `sc.list_packages()`:

```
aws-cfn-bootstrap (2.0)
beautifulsoup4 (4.9.1)
boto (2.49.0)
click (7.1.2)
docutils (0.14)
jmespath (0.10.0)
joblib (0.15.1)
lockfile (0.11.0)
lxml (4.5.1)
mysqlclient (1.4.2)
nltk (3.5)
nose (1.3.4)
numpy (1.16.5)
pip (9.0.1)
py-dateutil (2.2)
pystache (0.5.4)
python-daemon (2.2.3)
python37-sagemaker-pyspark (1.3.0)
pytz (2020.1)
PyYAML (5.3.1)
regex (2020.6.8)
setuptools (28.8.0)
simplejson (3.2.0)
six (1.13.0)
soupsieve (1.9.5)
tqdm (4.46.1)
UNKNOWN (1.3.5)
wheel (0.29.0)
windmill (1.6)

DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 22.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Note that `pandas`, `scipy` and `pip` are different. Why are they different? How do I upgrade or update the list in the `PySpark` notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Log into the master node and run sudo `docker ps -a`. You should see a container named something like `emr/jupyter-notebook:6.0.3` and that's where your Jupyter Notebook is running; it is not running in the master node.

If you decide to install any packages in the master node, the Jupyter Notebook will not see them. This is the reason why your packages do not match. To install packages in the Jupyter Notebook I use a requirements file, which contains the packages I want to install, and invoke a bootstrap action script that installs those packages. An important detail is to make sure that if you do specify a package version then it must be supported by the Python version running in the container. To find out just run a step in the Jupyter Notebook:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

To find the latest packages that go with a specific version of Python, I highly recommend using Anaconda. For example

```
conda create --name requests python=3.7.9 matplotlib
```

will tell me the latest version of matplotlib that works with Python 3.7.9